# Would you help me to find $C_n\|u_{m,n}\|^{\left(\frac{2*}{2}\right)^k\frac{2*-q}{(r_k)^k}}_{L^{2*}(\Omega)}$?

Tags: measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, sobolev-spaces

I'm studying a paper, which I'll include a small piece here. And I'm struggling to calculate

$$C_n\|u_{m,n}\|^{\left(\frac{2*}{2}\right)^k\frac{2*-q}{(r_k)^k}}_{L^{2*}(\Omega)}$$

Where $\Omega$ is an open, bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$.  We also are considering values of $m$ and $n$ such that $m>\overline{t}$, and $n>\max\{\overline{t}, \overline{n}\}$, given that $\overline{n}>0$, $\overline{t}=t_0+1$ with $t_0>0$. We also are considering $\gamma>1$, $2^{*}=\frac{2N}{N-2}> \gamma +2$ and $p$, $q$ are such that
\begin{align*}
\gamma+2&<p<\frac{2^*}{2}(\gamma +2)\\
\gamma+2&< q< \min\{p,2^*\}
\end{align*}
Remark: $\mathcal{S}^2$ is a constant of Sobolev, I mean appears after I used one of Sobolev embeddings theorem. Here $\alpha$ is a positive constant.

I tried to use Moser iteration. However, I do not understand where I'm making mistakes. I found the expression in (5) which is clearly different. Would you check if the expression in (6) is right?

I bet there is a very big problem, because since the basis $\left(\frac{(r_{k-1}-q+2)^2}{4\alpha S^2 (r_{k-1}-q+1)}\right)$ goes to infinity (by (4)), how can the whole expression obtained in (5) be smaller or equal to $\tilde{C}_n$?
[image: partial of page 165]

I've included the original paper in the link of google drive below. This part it is on page 165 of the paper.

David Arcoya, Lucio Boccardo, Luigi Orsina, "[Critical points for functionals with quasilinear singular Euler-Lagrange equations.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OngvGeX5510SpBxmVdaf57dFDEuprBuy/view?usp=sharing)", Calculus of Variations and Partial Differential Equations 47, No. 1-2, 159-180 (2013), [MR3044135](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR3044135), [Zbl 1266.35102](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1266.35102).

**MY ATTEMPT**

> Let's see the iteration

> \begin{equation}
> |u_{m,n}|_{L^{\frac{r-q+2}{2}2^*}(\Omega)}\leq \left(\frac{(r-q+2)^2}{4\alpha S^2 (r-q+1)}\right)^{\frac{1}{r-q+2}}n^{\frac{p-q}{r-q+2}}|u_{m,n}|_{L^r(\Omega)}^{\frac{r}{r-q+2}}\tag1
> \end{equation}

> Defining $r_0=2^*$ and $r_k=\left(\frac{2^*}{2}r_{k-1}+\frac{2^*}{(2-q)}\right)$. From (1) one has that

> \begin{align*}
> &|u_{m,n}|_{L^{r_k}(\Omega)}=|u_{m,n}|_{L^{\frac{(r_{k-1}-q+2)}{2}2^*}(\Omega)}\tag2\\
> &\leq\underbrace{\left(\frac{(r_{k-1}-q+2)^2}{4\alpha S^2 (r_{k-1}-q+1)}\right)^{\frac{1}{r_{k-1}-q+2}}n^{\frac{p-q}{r_{k-1}-q+2}}}_{C_1}|u_{m,n}|_{L^{r_{k-1}}(\Omega)}^{\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)\frac{r_{k-1}}{r_k}}\\
> &=C_1|u_{m,n}|_{L^{r_{k-1}}(\Omega)}^{\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)\frac{r_{k-1}}{r_k}}\\
> &\leq C_1\left\{\left(\frac{(r_{k-2}-q+2)^2}{4\alpha S^2 (r_{k-2}-q+1)}\right)^{\frac{1}{r_{k-2}-q+2}}n^{\frac{p-q}{r_{k-2}-q+2}}|u_{m,n}|_{L^{r_{k-2}}(\Omega)}^{\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)\frac{r_{k-2}}{r_{k-1}}}\right\}^{\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)\frac{r_{k-1}}{r_k}}\\
> &\leq C_1\underbrace{\left(\frac{(r_{k-2}-q+2)^2}{4\alpha S^2 (r_{k-2}-q+1)}\right)^{\frac{1}{r_{k-2}-q+2}\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)\frac{r_{k-1}}{r_k}}n^{\frac{p-q}{r_{k-2}-q+2}\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)\frac{r_{k-1}}{r_k}}}_{C_2}|u_{m,n}|_{L^{r_{k-2}}(\Omega)}^{\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^2\frac{r_{k-2}}{r_{k-1}}\frac{r_{k-1}}{r_k}}\\
> &=C_1C_2|u_{m,n}|_{L^{r_{k-2}}(\Omega)}^{\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^2\frac{r_{k-2}}{r_k}}\\
> &\leq C_1C_2\left\{\left(\frac{(r_{k-3}-q+2)^2}{4\alpha S^2(r_{k-3}-q+2)}\right)^{\frac{1}{r_{k-3}-q+2}}n^{\frac{p-q}{r_{k-3}-q+2}}|u_{m,n}|_{L^{r_{k-3}}(\Omega)}^{\frac{2^*}{2}\frac{r_{k-3}}{r_{k-2}}}\right\}^{\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^2\frac{r_{k-2}}{r_k}}\\
> &= C_1C_2\underbrace{\left(\frac{(r_{k-3}-q+2)^2}{4\alpha S^2(r_{k-3}-q+2)}\right)^{\frac{1}{r_{k-3}-q+2}\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^2\frac{r_{k-2}}{r_k}}n^{\frac{p-q}{r_{k-3}-q+2}\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^2\frac{r_{k-2}}{r_k}}}_{C_3}|u_{m,n}|_{L^{r_{k-3}}(\Omega)}^{\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^3\frac{r_{k-3}}{r_{k-2}}\frac{r_{k-2}}{r_k}}\\
> &= C_1C_2C_3|u_{m,n}|_{L^{r_{k-3}}(\Omega)}^{\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^3\frac{r_{k-3}}{r_k}}\\
> &\leq \cdots \leq\\
> &\leq C_1C_2C_3\cdots C_{k-1}\underbrace{\left(\frac{(r_{0}-q+2)^2}{4\alpha S^2(r_{0}-q+2)}\right)^{\frac{1}{r_{0}-q+2}\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^{k-1}\frac{r_1}{r_k}}n^{\frac{p-q}{r_{0}-q+2}\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^{k-1}\frac{r_1}{r_k}}}_{C_k}|u_{m,n}|_{{L^{2^*}}(\Omega)}^{\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^{k}\frac{r_0}{r_k}}
> \end{align*}

> Now rewriting the first powers in $C_1, C_2, ..., C_k$, it follows that in

> 1. item $C_1)$ \begin{align*}
>            \frac{1}{r_{k-1}-q+2}&=\frac{\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)}{\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)(r_{k-1}-q+2)}\\
>            &=\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)\frac{1}{r_k}
>        \end{align*}

> 2. item $C_2)$ \begin{align*}
>            \frac{1}{r_{k-2}-q+2}\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)\frac{r_{k-1}}{r_k}&=\frac{\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)}{\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)(r_{k-2}-q+2)}\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)\frac{r_{k-1}}{r_k}\\
>            &=\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^2\frac{1}{r_{k-1}}\frac{r_{k-1}}{r_k}\\
>            &=\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^2\frac{1}{r_k}\\
>            \end{align*}

> 3. item $C_3)$ \begin{align*}
>            \frac{1}{r_{k-3}-q+2}\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^2\frac{r_{k-2}}{r_k}&=\frac{\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)}{\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)(r_{k-3}-q+2)}\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^2\frac{r_{k-2}}{r_k}\\
>            &=\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^3\frac{1}{r_{k-2}}\frac{r_{k-2}}{r_k}\\
>            &=\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^3\frac{1}{r_k}
>            \end{align*}
>    $\vdots$

> 4. item $C_k)$ \begin{align*}
>        \frac{1}{{r_0}-q+2}\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^{k-1}\frac{r_1}{r_k}&=\frac{\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)}{\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)(r_0-q+2)}\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^{k-1}\frac{r_1}{r_k}\\
>        &=\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^k\frac{1}{r_1}\frac{r_1}{r_k}\\
>        &=\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^k\frac{1}{r_k}
>        \end{align*}

> Replacing properly the expressions above in every power of $C_1, C_2, ..., C_k$ it follows that
> \begin{align*}
> C_1&=\left(\frac{(r_{k-1}-q+2)^2}{4\alpha S^2(r_{k-1}-q+1)}\right)^{\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)\frac{1}{r_k}}n^{(p-q)\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)\frac{1}{r_k}}\\
> C_2&=\left(\frac{(r_{k-2}-q+2)^2}{4\alpha S^2(r_{k-2}-q+1)}\right)^{\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^2\frac{1}{r_k}}n^{(p-q)\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^2\frac{1}{r_k}}\\
> &\vdots\\
>  C_k&=\left(\frac{(r_0-q+2)^2}{4\alpha S^2(r_0-q+1)}\right)^{\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^k\frac{1}{r_k}}n^{(p-q)\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^k\frac{1}{r_k}}\\
> \end{align*}
> Rewriting the whole expression in (2) replacing the exponents as above, one has that
> \begin{align*}
>    |u_{m,n}|_{L^{r_k}}&\leq \left[\left(\frac{(r_{k-1}-q+2)^2}{4\alpha S^2(r_{k-1}-q+1)}\right)n^{(p-q)}\right]^{\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)\frac{1}{r_k}}\\
> &\cdot \left[\left(\frac{(r_{k-2}-q+2)^2}{4\alpha S^2(r_{k-2}-q+1)}\right)n^{(p-q)}\right]^{\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^2\frac{1}{r_k}}\\
> &\vdots\\
> &\cdot\left[\left(\frac{(r_0-q+2)^2}{4\alpha S^2(r_0-q+1)}\right)n^{(p-q)}\right]^{\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^k\frac{1}{r_k}}\cdot |u_{m,n}|_{L^{2^*}(\Omega)}^{\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^k\frac{r_0}{r_k}}\tag3\\
> \end{align*}
> Considering $r_0=2^*$. Since $\frac{2^*}{2}>1$, let's prove that $r_k$ is an increasing sequence which diverges to infinity.

> Indeed, note that if
>
> 1. item $(k=1)$
>    \begin{align*}
>        r_1&=\frac{2^*}{2}(r_0-q+2)\\
>        &=\frac{2}{2^*}=r_0+(2-q)\\
>    \end{align*}
>    Subtracting $\frac{2}{2^*}r_0$ in both sides, it follows that
>    \begin{align*}
>        \frac{2}{2^*}(r_1-r_0)&=r_0-\frac{2}{2^*}r_0+(2-q)\\
>        &=2^*-\frac{2}{2^*}2^*+2-q \\
>        &=2^*-q>0
>    \end{align*}
>    Thus $r_1>r_0$.
> 2. item $(k=2)$ , similarly
>    \begin{align*}
>       \frac{2}{2^*}(r_2-r_1)&=r_1-\frac{2}{2^*}r_1+(2-q)\\
>        &=\frac{2^*}{2}(r_0-q+2)-r_0+q-2-q+2\\
>        &=\frac{(2^*)^2-2^*q+22^*-22^*}{2}\\
>        &=\frac{2^*}{2}(2^*-q)>0
>    \end{align*}
>    Therefore, $r_2>r_1$.

> Proceeding in this way indefinitelyt, one can find that $r_k$ is an increasing sequence, that is $r_0<r_1<r_2<...<r_k<...$ and its limit is
> $$\lim_{k\to \infty}r_k=+\infty.$$
> One claims that
> $$\left(\frac{(r_0-q+2)^2}{4\alpha S^2(r_0-q+1)}\right)<\left(\frac{(r_1-q+2)^2}{4\alpha S^2(r_1-q+1)}\right)<...<\left(\frac{(r_k-q+2)^2}{4\alpha S^2(r_k-q+1)}\right)<...\tag4$$
> Indeed, taking $t=r_0, r_1, r_2, ..., r_k,...$ and defining
> $$f(t)=\frac{(t-q+2)^2}{4\alpha S^2 (t-q+1)}$$
> one has that
> \begin{align*}
> f'(t)&=\frac{2(t-q+2)4\alpha S^2(t-q+1)-(t-q+2)^24\alpha S^2}{4\alpha S^2(t-q+1)^2}\\
> &=\frac{(t-q+2)[2t-2q+2-t+q-2]}{(t-q+1)^2}
> \end{align*}
> In order to show that $f$ is an increasing function one only needs to get that $(t-q+2)(t-q)>0$ and this is true, first note that if $t=r_0$ then $(2^*-q+2)(2^*-q)>0$ once $2^*-q>0$. Now, by (4), replacing every single value for $t$ one has that $f'(t)>0$ which implies that $f$ is an increasing function. Hence one has proved the claim.
> Now turning back to (3) replacing the result in (4), one can rewrite (3) as
> $$|u_{m,n}|_{L^{r_k}(\Omega)}\leq \left[\left(\frac{(r_{k-1}-q+2)^2}{4\alpha S^2(r_{k-1}-q+1)}\right)n^{(p-q)}\right]^{\frac{1}{r_k}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{k}\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^i}|u_{m,n}|_{L^{2^*}(\Omega)}^{\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^k\frac{r_0}{r_k}}.\tag5$$
> On the other hand, notice that, taking $A=\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)(2-q)$ one can rewrite $r_k$ as
> \begin{align*}
> r_k&=r_{k-1}\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)(2-q)\\
> &=r_{k-1}\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)+A\\
> &=\left(r_{k-2}\left(\frac{2^*}{2}+A\right)\right)\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)+A\\
> &=\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^2r_{k-2}+\left(1+\frac{2^*}{2}\right)A\\
> &=\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^2\left[r_{k-3}\left(\frac{2^*}{2}+A\right)\right]+\left(1+\frac{2^*}{2}\right)A\\
> &=\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^3r_{k-3}+\left(1+\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^2\right)A\\
> &\vdots\\
> &=\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^kr_0+A+A\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)+A\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^2+...+A\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^{k-1}
> \end{align*}
> what is the same as $r_k=\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^kr_0+A\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^i$, this is
> $$r_k=\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^kr_0+(2-q)\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)\left[\frac{1-\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)^{k-1}}{1-\left(\frac{2^*}{2}\right)}\right].\tag6$$

**I really appreciate if someone can help me!
Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Maybe posting it on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) could be helpful.

Comment: @DanDoe Hi. Thanks, do you think if I only copy and past would be helpful? Because I do not know how to transfer bounty from here to there.

Comment: I think on MO there are less questions in general, so you might get attention anyways.

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: I would not recommend posting this on MO. In rambles, with no clear question, no organization.

Comment: @amWhy  First of all I apologize for searching for you here in a place where it is not supposed for me to comment here. But, please, help me with this? I only would like at least a hint, a small tip.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4797950/what-hypothesis-can-i-assume-in-order-to-obtain-infinity-solutions-for-this-prob